# Load file from input type = file , Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have input

```
            <input
                accept="image/*"
                id="contained-button-file"
                multiple
                type="file"
            />
```

And i want to load the file selected using:

```
 const selectedFile = ( document.getElementById('contained-button-file') as HTMLInputElement  ).files[0];
```

But Typescript complains:

`TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.`

How can i work around this or make sure it has file selected ( as i want to send it to server ) ?

THanks for help

Comment: Well, add an `if` statement.

Comment: and by explicitly saying that the result can be `as HTMLInputElement | null`, since TS has no way of knowing whether querySelector will actually match anything at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
const selectedFile = (
  document.getElementById('contained-button-file') as HTMLInputElement
).files![0];
```

This says that `files` will not be null, which is true in this case. TS just doesn't know that the input is of type `file`.

---

Error handling solution

```
const element = document.getElementById('contained-button-file');
if (!element || !(element instanceof HTMLInputElement))
  throw Error('Could not retrieve file input element');

const input = element as HTMLInputElement;
if (!input.files) throw Error('File input is not of type "file"');

const selectedFile = input.files[0];
```

Typescript is able to see that you've put these guards in place and knows that the objects cannot be null in the code underneath them.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if files is truthy then get files[0]

```
const input = document.getElementById('contained-button-file') as HTMLInputElement;
const file = input.files ? input.files[0] : null;
```